# Lucene IndexSearcher - Search if an indexed value is contained in user input

Tags: java, indexing, lucene, full-text-search

I have an indexed table which contains titles of movies.

```
{"Titanic", "Fight Club", "Pulp Fiction"}
```

My users input query will in most cases be a longer string, which might contain a movie name from my DB.

E.g. "*The movie **Fight Club** is my favorite movie ever!*"

I am trying to find a "lucene" way, to search the index, if any of the movies in my DB is a substring (case insensitive) of the user input.

Reading the [lucene Query docs](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_2_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Query.html), seems to me that all queries could achieve the exact opposite of my needs, i.e. user input contained in indexed value, but not indexed value contained in user input.

Am I missing here something? Or is there a different approach to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

One way I can think of is to add an additional pass to your search results. By default, when you search for "The movie Fight Club is my favorite movie ever!", You'll get results for documents "Fight Club", "Club Fight", "I had a fight at club today". Now you can do an additional naive search on the top documents to filter out just "Fight Club". For case-insensitive, you just need to add a lowercase tokenfilter to your index and search analyzer. Also make sure the stopwords are removed, so that your second pass doesn't have to go through too many documents.